# ArrayList<MyClass> issues

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I'm trying to get all possible word couples from a sentence and store it to an **ArrayList**
where **MyClass.java**

```
class MyClass{

private static ArrayList<String> wordList;
private static ArrayList<Integer> wordListCode;
private static int frequency;
private static int timeId;

public MyClass(ArrayList<String> words, int tid, int freq){
    wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    wordListCode = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(words.get(0).hashCode()> words.get(1).hashCode()){
        wordList.add(words.get(0));    wordListCode.add(words.get(0).hashCode());
        wordList.add(words.get(1));    wordListCode.add(words.get(1).hashCode());
    }else{
        wordList.add(words.get(1));    wordListCode.add(words.get(1).hashCode());
        wordList.add(words.get(0));    wordListCode.add(words.get(0).hashCode());
    }
    frequency = freq;
    timeId = tid;
}}
```

My problem is that when I'm trying to add an **MyClass** object to the **ArrayList**, adds one *node* but replaces all the other *nodes* with the values of the last one...

Here is some code:

```
 ArrayList<MyClass> couples = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    ArrayList<String[]> couplesList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    couplesList = getWordCouplesList("demanding forensic technical comms systems");
    for(int o=0; o<couplesList.size(); o++){
        String word1, word2;
        if(couplesList.get(o)[0].hashCode()> couplesList.get(o)[1].hashCode() ){
            word1 = couplesList.get(o)[0];
            word2 = couplesList.get(o)[1];
        }else{
            word1 = couplesList.get(o)[1];
            word2 = couplesList.get(o)[0];
        }
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(couplesList.get(o)));
        MyClass temp = new MyClass((ArrayList)items, 1, 1);
        couples.add( temp);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<couples.size(); i++){
        System.out.println((i+1)+"couple = "+couples.get(i).getWordList().get(0)+" , "+couples.get(i).getWordList().get(1));
    }
```

---

This gives output :

```
1couple = comms , systems
2couple = comms , systems
3couple = comms , systems
4couple = comms , systems
5couple = comms , systems
6couple = comms , systems
7couple = comms , systems
8couple = comms , systems
9couple = comms , systems
10couple = comms , systems
```

Comment: Read up on static vs non-static.

Comment: that's because your fields in your class are static

Comment: thank you guys! I didn't notice it at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyClass {

  private ArrayList<String> wordList;
  private ArrayList<Integer> wordListCode;
  private int frequency;
  private int timeId;
  ...
  .....
}
```

remove the `static` modifier on your fields.

it means you use the same instance for every object of that `MyClass`, which you don't want. You want every instance to have it's own lists and attributes.

[read more about it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `static` modifier.

From `JLS 8.3.1.1. static Fields`

> If a field is declared static, there exists exactly one incarnation of
>   the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class
>   may eventually be created. A static field, sometimes called a class
>   variable, is incarnated when the class is initialized (§12.4).
>
> A field that is not declared static (sometimes called a non-static
>   field) is called an instance variable. Whenever a new instance of a
>   class is created (§12.5), a new variable associated with that instance
>   is created for every instance variable declared in that class or any
>   of its superclasses.

For more info refer,  [static Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1)

So change your code to,

```
class MyClass{

  private ArrayList<String> wordList;
  private ArrayList<Integer> wordListCode;
  private int frequency;
  private int timeId;
  ...
  .....
}}
```